# Atlassian bamboo: Ant deploy task keeps failing

Tags: deployment, ant, bamboo

I have a deployment project setup via Atlassian bamboo.

The steps are being executed successfully until the Apache Ant task.

I don't know what is going wrong; if I execute the command on the server it works without any errors.

```
-bash-4.1$ ant -q -f httpdocs/build.xml cpparam

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

In the bamboo logfile I see the following output:

```
24-Jul-2014 15:45:26    Starting task 'Copy the parameters dist' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.ant:task.builder.ant'
24-Jul-2014 15:45:26    
Beginning to execute external process for build 'Deployment of 'release-7' on '*********** CI01''
 ... running command line: 
/opt/ant-1.8/bin/ant -f /var/www/vhosts/***********/httpdocs/build.xml -q cpparam
 ... in: /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/26050561-26148865
 ... using extra environment variables: 
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-7
bamboo_planRepository_type=bb
bamboo_shortPlanName=CI Build
bamboo_planName=*********** - CI Build
bamboo_planKey=***********
bamboo_planRepository_revision=***********
bamboo_buildResultKey=***********-CB-18
bamboo_planRepository_1_revision=***********
ANT_HOME=/opt/ant-1.8
bamboo_planRepository_1_type=bb
bamboo_planRepository_1_branchName=development
bamboo_planRepository_1_name=Bitbucket
bamboo_test=test
bamboo_buildNumber=18
bamboo_planRepository_name=Bitbucket
bamboo_shortPlanKey=CB
bamboo_planRepository_branchName=development
PATH=/opt/jdk-7/bin:/opt/bamboo-elastic-agent/bin:/opt/jdk-6/bin:/opt/maven-2.1/bin:/opt/maven-1.0.2/bin:/opt/ant-1.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/bin:/bin
24-Jul-2014 15:45:26    Failing task since return code of [/opt/ant-1.8/bin/ant -f httpdocs/build.xml cpparam] was -1 while expected 0
24-Jul-2014 15:45:26    Finished task 'Copy the parameters dist'
24-Jul-2014 15:45:26    Finalising the build...
24-Jul-2014 15:45:26    Stopping timer.
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this?
In the build plan everything works like a charm.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

If I run the `ant` command directly on the server with `-verbose`

```
-bash-4.1$ ant -f httpdocs/build.xml -verbose cpparam
Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on August 24 2010
Buildfile: httpdocs/build.xml
Detected Java version: 1.6 in: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre
Detected OS: Linux
parsing buildfile /var/www/vhosts/test/httpdocs/build.xml with URI = file:/var/www/vhosts/test/httpdocs/build.xml
Project base dir set to: /var/www/vhosts/test/httpdocs
Build sequence for target(s) `cpparam' is [cpparam]
Complete build sequence is [cpparam, cache, logs, lint, assets, clean, fixtures, dbupdate, prepare, phpunit, dlcomposer, behat, build, assetic, behat:chrome, ]

cpparam:
[antlib:org.apache.tools.ant] Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /var/www/vhosts/test/httpdocs/app/config
     [copy] Copying /var/www/vhosts/test/httpdocs/app/config/parameters.yml.dist to /var/www/vhosts/test/httpdocs/app/config/parameters.yml

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

The complete bamboo deployment log file with the -verbose

```
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:17:20    Build Deployment of 'release-7' on '**** CI01' started building on agent Elastic Agent on i-9beb61db
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:17:20    Build working directory is /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/26050561-26148865
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:17:20    Executing build Deployment of 'release-7' on '**** CI01'
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:17:20    Starting task 'Clean working directory task' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-artifact-downloader-plugin:cleanWorkingDirectoryTask'
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:17:20    Cleaning working directory '/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/26050561-26148865'
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:17:20    Finished task 'Clean working directory task' with result: Success
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:17:20    Starting task 'Download release contents' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-artifact-downloader-plugin:artifactdownloadertask'
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:17:20    Preparing to download plan result ****-CB-18 artifact: Shared artifact: [Symfony2 tarball], pattern: [sf2.tar.gz]
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:21    Artifact [Symfony2 tarball] downloaded successfully in 61s to working directory
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:21    Finished task 'Download release contents' with result: Success
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:21    Starting task 'SCP the tarball to his location' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-scp-plugin:scptask'
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:25    Connecting to ci01.****-ops.net on port: 22
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:26    Uploading '/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/26050561-26148865/sf2.tar.gz' to '/var/www/vhosts/niko-oqt.ci01.****ci.be/releases'...
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:55    '/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/26050561-26148865/sf2.tar.gz' was uploaded successfully.
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:55    Finished task 'SCP the tarball to his location' with result: Success
command 31-Jul-2014 09:18:56    Substituting variable: ${bamboo.deploy.release} with release-7
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:56    Starting task 'Extract tarball' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-scp-plugin:sshtask'
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:56    Connecting to ci01.****-ops.net on port: 22
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:56    Executing [
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:56    # variables
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:56    DIRNAME=release-7
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:56    
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:56    # Create release directory
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:56    mkdir -p releases/$DIRNAME
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:56    
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:56    # Extract that Drupal tarball.
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:56    tar xzf releases/sf2.tar.gz -C releases/$DIRNAME
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:56    
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:56    # Remove the tarball
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:56    rm -f releases/sf2.tar.gz
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:18:56    ]
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:03    [
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:03    # variables
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:03    DIRNAME=release-7
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:03    
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:03    # Create release directory
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:03    mkdir -p releases/$DIRNAME
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:03    
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:03    # Extract that sf tarball.
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:03    tar xzf releases/sf2.tar.gz -C releases/$DIRNAME
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:03    
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:03    # Remove the tarball
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:03    rm -f releases/sf2.tar.gz
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:03    ] has finished.
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:03    Result: exit code = 0
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:03    Finished task 'Extract tarball' with result: Success
command 31-Jul-2014 09:19:03    Substituting variable: ${bamboo.deploy.release} with release-7
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:03    Starting task 'Add links' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-scp-plugin:sshtask'
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:03    Connecting to ci01.****-ops.net on port: 22
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    Executing [
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    # variables
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    DIRNAME=release-7
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    # remove the current http root link
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    rm -f httpdocs
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    # Link the release to the http root.
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    ln -s releases/$DIRNAME/www httpdocs
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    ]
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    [
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    # variables
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    DIRNAME=release-7
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    # remove the current http root link
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    rm -f httpdocs
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    # Link the release to the http root.
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    ln -s releases/$DIRNAME/www httpdocs
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    ] has finished.
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    Result: exit code = 0
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    Finished task 'Add links' with result: Success
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:04    Starting task 'Copy the parameters dist' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.ant:task.builder.ant'
command 31-Jul-2014 09:19:05    Beginning to execute external process for build 'Deployment of 'release-7' on '**** CI01''\n ... running command line: \n/opt/ant-1.8/bin/ant -f httpdocs/build.xml -verbose cpparam\n ... in: /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/26050561-26148865/var/www/vhosts/niko-oqt.ci01.****ci.be\n ... using extra environment variables: \nbamboo_deploy_environment=**** CI01\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_grailsBuilder_Grails_1_3=/opt/grails-1.3\nbamboo_capability_system_jdk_JDK_1_6=/opt/jdk-6\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_grailsBuilder_Grails_1_2=/opt/grails-1.2\nbamboo_capability_system_jdk_JDK_1_7=/opt/jdk-7\nJAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-7\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_Drupal_remove_development_files=/opt/****-scripts/drupal/remove_development_files.sh\nbamboo_planRepository_type=bb\nbamboo_shortPlanName=CI Build\nbamboo_planKey=****-CB\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_****_Bitbucket_checkout=/opt/****-scripts/bitbucket_checkout.sh\nbamboo_capability_system_jdk_JDK_1_5=/opt/jdk-5\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_Compass=/usr/bin/compass\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_node_Node_js_0_10=/opt/node-0.10/bin/node\nbamboo_planRepository_1_branchName=development\nbamboo_deploy_release=release-7\nbamboo_shortPlanKey=CB\nbamboo_build_working_directory=/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/26050561-26148865\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_mvn3_Maven_3_0=/opt/maven-3.0\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_Symfony2_remove_development_files=/opt/****-scripts/symfony/remove_development_files.sh\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_Drupal_coder_sniffer=/opt/****-scripts/drupal/php_codesniffer_drupal.sh\nbamboo_planName=Niko - OQT - CI Build\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_phpunit_PHPUnit_3_4=/usr/bin/phpunit-3.4\nbamboo_planRepository_revision=42de29f040d3066afbc1596fc4caefd69aaa5540\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_phpunit_PHPUnit_3_7=/usr/bin/phpunit-3.7\nbamboo_buildResultKey=****-CB-18\nbamboo_capability_system_git_executable=/usr/bin/git\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_mvn2_Maven_2_1=/opt/maven-2.1\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_mvn2_Maven_2_2=/opt/maven-2.2\nbamboo_test=test\nbamboo_working_directory=/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/26050561-26148865\nbamboo_deploy_release_previous=release-7\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_mvn2_Maven_2_0=/opt/maven-2.0\nbamboo_agentWorkingDirectory=/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_ant_Ant_1_8=/opt/ant-1.8\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_Drush=/usr/bin/drush\nbamboo_resultsUrl=https://****.atlassian.net/builds/deploy/viewDeploymentResult.action?deploymentResultId=26935324\nbamboo_deploy_rollback=false\nbamboo_planRepository_1_revision=42de29f040d3066afbc1596fc4caefd69aaa5540\nbamboo_ManualBuildTriggerReason_userName=evert.vancauwenberg\nbamboo_planRepository_1_type=bb\nbamboo_planRepository_1_name=Bitbucket\nbamboo_capability_system_hg_executable=/usr/bin/hg\nbamboo_planRepository_branchName=development\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_Check_for_dpm=/opt/****-scripts/drupal/check_for_dpm.sh\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_mvn2_Maven_2=/opt/maven-2.2\nbamboo_deploy_version_previous=release-7\nbamboo_agentId=26574851\nANT_HOME=/opt/ant-1.8\nbamboo_deploy_version=release-7\nbamboo_planRepository_name=Bitbucket\nbamboo_buildNumber=18\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_grailsBuilder_Grails_2_0=/opt/grails-2.0\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_grailsBuilder_Grails_2_1=/opt/grails-2.1\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_grailsBuilder_Grails_2_2=/opt/grails-2.2\nbamboo_deploy_project=Deployment for *** - OQT\nPATH=/opt/jdk-7/bin:/opt/bamboo-elastic-agent/bin:/opt/jdk-6/bin:/opt/maven-2.1/bin:/opt/maven-1.0.2/bin:/opt/ant-1.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/bin:/bin\n
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:05    Failing task since return code of [/opt/ant-1.8/bin/ant -f httpdocs/build.xml -verbose cpparam] was -1 while expected 0
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:05    Finished task 'Copy the parameters dist' with result: Failed
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:05    Finalising the build...
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:05    Stopping timer.
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:05    Build 26050561-26148865-26935324 completed.
simple  31-Jul-2014 09:19:05    Finished processing deployment result Deployment of 'release-7' on '**** CI01'
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `-q` option from the Ant command in Bamboo? `-q` tells Ant to "be extra quiet" and this option may be hiding valuable information.

Comment: Is this permission related? Check the account that bamboo is running under has relevant permission.

Comment: Without the -q it gives the same result.
What do you mean permission related? 
All the other tasks work .. ssh, scp, ...

Comment: Please edit your question so the Bamboo log example shows what happens when the `-q` option is removed. Even better, edit the configuration in Bamboo so the Ant command line uses the `-verbose` option. Then add the new Bamboo log output to your question.

Comment: I have edited the question with the new logfile using the -verbose parameter.

Comment: Someone gat any idea, i have fixed it temporary wit han ssh task that does the ant task but this is not ideal.